# change image when mouse over an image using #map

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, mouse

I have added a database connection to [this site](http://ppr.rj45tech.info) and made it dynamic. The design of the website was already done, I just added the database connection.

Everything's fine, but now I had added the jQuery Carousel, but I can't change the image of menu (i.e. menu,company profile etc.) when I hover with the mouse.

I tried all possible things (I saw that the menus are designed with #map) but I couldn't solve this problem.

Comment: cant you just do it in css? or javascript?

Comment: i had tried but because of these are images i can't do it.

Comment: The Lot of you ok so he's new and made a stupid mistake, but that's what this community is there for to help not just insult people i have corrected the tags

Comment: @micha Thanks for your suggestion.Lets take only d Home part.The menu bar code only 4 home is...<tr>
        <td><img src="images/home.jpg" width="145" height="50" /></td>
        </tr>                                                       Then how u will apply hover to this.I just only want to know this.If it is designed using <div> or <a href> then i will solve this and there is no need to post the question.Either this problem is not so simple as u thinking or i am thinking the solution too complexly.Thanks...

Comment: @Martin Barker  Thanks...Exactly right what u want to say..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a jQuery example for the home button:

```
$("table:first table:first tr:eq(1) td:first img").hover(function() {
    $(this).attr("src", "image.jpg");
},
function() {
    $(this).attr("src", "home.jpg");
});
```

Additional fixes which should be done on your page:

- The `webticker_lib.js` file isn't in use. (The element with the id TICKER doesn't exists)
- The function goforit which you call onload isn't defined anywhere.
- Please add cursor: pointer; to the drop down menu
- Please add 15px padding (right and left) to the marquee:

```
marquee {
    padding: 0 15px;
}
```